# looking for per-user, no-source-controlled config file overrides, in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, development-environment

Is there a way in Rails 3 to allow a user to override the Rails configs with a file that does not go into source control?

Even though the 'environments' feature is powerful, providing a 'development' environment out-of-the-box, you still want to give developers a way  override even those development defaults for configs that are developer-machine independent.

What I'm hoping for is something like this:

*A developer can create a file, config/environments/user.rb  that never is checked into git.  The developer can do whatever they want in there, and not accidentally affect others using the same source tree.*

Comment: A) You can exclude any single file from git, just google how. One option is placing a reference to it in your `.gitignore` file. 

B) Take a look at the [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro). It uses this approach and helps you organize your environment variables in a `config/application.yml` file which it excludes in `.gitignore`.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm I know about .gitignore, thanks.  Regarding figaro, it looks like it doesn't do overrides of Rails configuration system; just creates a second configuration system that is left out of source control for private configs.  That's not the point, but thanks.

Comment: For what reason would you like to create a separate config for one app depending on developer machines?

Comment: I've wanted this on every project I've ever worked on.  Here is an example though.  Say there is a username and password baked into developer.rb to a server-side component that every developer must install to run the rails app. And say there is one developer who really wants to have a different username & password.  Fine, override.    So most developers don't have to mess with custom configs to get going... but at least there is a way out for the outlier.

Comment: You are talking only about variables?

Comment: @ThomasKlemm I don't understand the question.